# How to change first day of week in Kendo react UI calendar library

Tags: kendo-datepicker, kendo-react-ui

Default first day of a week in Kendo React JS's calendar library is **Sunday**.

Want starting day of a week should be **Monday**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is localized using the IntlProvider, see the [documentation in the KendoReact site](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dateinputs/globalization/). In the example the calendar starts from Monday, and not Sunday, since it is using ES culture.
The IntlProvider provides the cultures to the DatePicker including the first day of week. 
You can load the data from [CLDR as it is from their repo](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-core/blob/cldr-34/supplemental/weekData.json). Or modify it first to match your needs and then load it. For example: `weekData.supplemental.weekData.firstDay.US = 'mon';`

Here is such override example with full code:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    import { Calendar } from '@progress/kendo-react-dateinputs';
    import { IntlProvider, load } from '@progress/kendo-react-intl';

    import likelySubtags from 'cldr-core/supplemental/likelySubtags.json';
    import currencyData from 'cldr-core/supplemental/currencyData.json';
    import weekData from 'cldr-core/supplemental/weekData.json';

    load(likelySubtags, currencyData, weekData);

    weekData.supplemental.weekData.firstDay.US = 'mon';

    class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <IntlProvider locale={'en-US'}>
            <div className="example-wrapper row">
            <Calendar />
            </div>
        </IntlProvider>
        );
    }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.querySelector('my-app')
    );
```

And [here is live version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ml1lzc?file=app/main.js) of the above.